# How to make the numbers automatically using jquery append ..?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello all I want to ask, how to make the numbers automatically using jquery append ..?
I have made ​​it but still failed
My source code is :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Help Help</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="button" id="button" value="Create a number from 1 to N"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#button').click(function()
            {
                $('#result').append('<div class="number">Numbers To ......</div>');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
<hr>
results from click button
<hr>
<div id=result></div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What numbers are you talking about? Do you want to generate a random number on each button click? If so, what is your problem? Don't you know how to create random numbers?

Comment: @Felix, yeah. That's what I thought, too; until I saw the `input` element's `value`. I assume he wants to create a sequence of numbers, from `0` through to `n`, in the `div` of `#result`. Though that really is a best-guess attempt...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
$('#numbers').change(
    function(){
        var max = $(this).val();
        var sequence;
        for(i=0; i<=max; i++) {
            var text = $('#result').text();
            if (text == false){
                text = i;
            }
            else if (i == max) {
                text = text + ', ' + i + '.';
            }
            else {
                text = text + ', ' + i;
            }
            $('#result').text(text);
        }
    });

$('form').submit(
    function(){
        return false;
    });
```

With the following, simplified, html:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <label for="numbers">Make a sequence of numbers, from one to <em>n</em></label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="1000" step="1" id="numbers" name="numbers" />
</form>

<div id="result">
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rb78q/1/).

---

**Edited** to offer a more concise version of the above jQuery code, as offered by mplungjan (in comments, below):

```
$('#numbers').change(
    function(){
        var max = $(this).val(),text="";
        for(i=1; i<=max; i++) {
            text += ', ' + i;
        }
        if(text) $('#result').text(text.substring(2)+".");
    });

$('form').submit(
    function(){
        return false;
    });
```

[Revised/optimised jQuery at JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Gbrm/1/)

Answer convertd to community wiki, since earning rep from someone else's efforts just seems wrong....

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks :) I really hadn't bothered to try to optimise it, just in case it wasn't what the OP wanted...would you mind if I edit it into my answer, or would you rather post your own?

Comment: Hmm - difficult ;) could need the flair but might not get it anyway ;) go ahead, update yours

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks! Because I'd feel bad taking rep from someone else's efforts I've converted the answer to community wiki. :)